# Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Auto Increment

Tags: google-apps-script

In Spreadsheet, If I select ST on 'Trial' column C0001-ST1 will appear in 'Code' column then if I select SP in 'Trial' column C0002-SP1 will appear in 'Code' column then if I again select ST in 'Trial' column C0003-ST2 will appear in 'Code' column.

**Step 1:**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

This is the code that I've now to achieve this.

```
function incTrialCode(sectionCode) { 
    if (sectionCode == ""){ return null; } 

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    for (i=1; i<values.length; i++)
    { 
        trial = values[i][1];
    } 
    return sectionCode + values;
 }
```

Comment: @Reyman: I'm assuming what you explained above is your desired behaviour. What have you already done to achieve this? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @sudobangbang: Yes, that is what I want to behave. First I want to create a script that will increment C0001, C0002, C0003 and so on. Then create another script to know how many duplicates in 'Trial' column. Then put the two scripts together.

Comment: @Reyman: Could you share some code? These might come in handy

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles#basics-custom-functions

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: @sudobangbang: I'm a beginner so i only have this. function incTrialCode(sectionCode) {
  if (sectionCode == ""){
    return null;
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  for (i=1; i<values.length; i++){
        
    trial = values[i][1];
    
    
  }
  return sectionCode + values;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script.

You can put this formula in column A
`="C"&text(counta(B$2:B2),"0000")&"-"&B2&countif(B$2:B2,B2)`

Start at row 2 and drag it down to incorporate all cells. See it in action [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165f9vxD-NvCQ6YUK2Gh9ycuiwVfXne0AxW4kqIq_wgo/edit#gid=0).

If you need it explained, let me know.

Comment: I'm getting Formula parse error. Also can you add year in the middle. Like this C0001-16-ST01. 16 is the year todate.

Comment: `=if(isblank(B2),"","C"&text(counta(B$2:B2),"0000")&"-"&right(year(today()),2)&"-"&B2&countif(B$2:B2,B2))` is the formula for the year in the middle. Now go check [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165f9vxD-NvCQ6YUK2Gh9ycuiwVfXne0AxW4kqIq_wgo/edit#gid=0) and see for yourself that it works as you requested. If you've got other errors, it's probably due to your spreadsheet locale settings or you have other formulas as well in column `B:B`. Have you tried fixing the parse error somehow?